# Wordpress custom pagination function issue

Tags: wordpress, loops, pagination

I'm working on a custom pagination with a custom loop to be displayed anywhere on the page. I worked out the code in functions.php file like this

```
function custom_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

And an additional loop to be called in any place which I've placed in a template file:

```
<?php $additional_loop = new WP_Query("cat=0&paged=$paged"); ?>

<?php while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : $additional_loop->the_post();   ?>

<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php custom_pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);?>
```

But the additional loop doesn't show all pages. For example, when I call only `custom_pagination();` the last page in pagination is 41. But when I call `custom_pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);` on another location, the last page is 9. 
I think I have done something wrong in the part `<?php $additional_loop = new WP_Query("cat=0&paged=$paged"); ?>` but can't figure out what is it. 

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might reside in the fact that you are using `new WP_Query`, but are failing to [reset the query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop) after your `endwhile`. Try adding `wp_reset_postdata();`.  Another, possibly safer option would be to use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts); instead?  Very similar to what you are already doing, but get_posts() will not alter the loop as WP_Query does (which is why you need to reset the post data after you use it).